# How do I access Kernel Parameters inside a Doctrine2 Migration in Symfony2

Tags: dependency-injection, doctrine, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working in Symfony2 and I'd like to get access to the Kernel so that I can call getRootDir(. I need to do this from a Doctrine2 Migration. Doctrine2 migrations extend AbstractMigration and aren't container aware so I guess I would need to add this in. What is the best way to do this, I can implement the interface but im not sure how to get it working? Can anyone provide a solution/example?

Cheers

Comment: 'Quick fix' for this is to use "______DIR______" (since migrations are one dir off the kernel dir by default). This is obviously not the correct way to fix this however.

Comment: I think `__DIR__` is a good approach, since your class is not at all about Symfony's kernel. You shouldn't couple together two different subjects. Migrations classes are doctrine specific and have nothing to do with symfony. They should be reusable in a totally different context.

Comment: Well, Doctrine2 migrations have a config tree that chooses where to place the DoctrineMigrations based on the kernel.rootDir. When you need to know where to place something you kind of need to know where the rootdir is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a bundle for you:

https://github.com/kbond/ZenstruckMigrationsBundle

To make use of container aware data migrations your migrations must extend:

```
Zenstruck\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\Migrations\AbstractMigration
```